# Deprivation and privation

Tags: meaning, synonyms, word-usage, redundancy, negative-prefixes

"Deprivation" and "privation" seem to have the same meaning: the denial of material essentials or comforts. Isn't the prefix "de-" redundant? Is there a difference, either in literal usage or connotation, between these two words?

Comment: I think "de-" in this case means that things have been taken from you. If you are in a state of privation, that can occur in many ways, but to *deprive* is to take away. So a state of *deprivation* means that you have been denied material essentials, or have had them taken away, while *privation* doesn't necessarily have that requirement.

Comment: We use the word _dehydration_ even when water isn't necessarily being held back: "Desert travelers are in constant fear of dehydration."
This may be an exception, though, as privation already means the absence of things; it may be the redundancy per se that gives "de-" a different meaning.

Comment: That might be the case. "de-" has many meanings, one of which, according to dicitonary.com, is "privation": http://www.dictionary.com/browse/de-

Answer (score 3):

The reasoning that appeals to me here is the sense of "entirely" for the prefix "de-". (Acknowledgements to [etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=deprive&allowed_in_frame=0)). Privation might be simply me being separated from my cat for a day. Deprivation would imply that my cat died.

Privation of water from beans is not enough for them to be stored well; they should be deprived of water, desiccated, and then they will store.

Common usage of course has blurred the distinction. Can I be deprived of my rights? I can always get them back at some point if lost; but if the temporary separation from the right results in my death, then the result is extreme.

Since the true meaning of de- is lost in time like tears in rain, this is only one of many possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

From M-W:

> [*deprivation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprivation):
>   the state of being deprived
>
> [*deprived*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deprived): not
>   having the things that are needed for a good or healthy life
>
> [*privation*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/privation): an
>   act or instance of depriving : deprivation / the state of being
>   deprived; especially : lack of what is needed for existence

Based on these definitions, *deprivation* and *privation* seem to mean almost the same thing. If there is a difference, it concerns "not having the things that are needed for a good and healthy life" (*deprivation*) and "lack of what is needed for existence" (*privation*). From the point of view of life, having to endure *privation* seems slightly worse than having to endure *deprivation*.

Comment: Definitions vary from dictionary to dictionary. I'm interested if there are people who can differentiate when one or the other would be a better choice, though the difference is so slight that it should not matter.

Comment: @Symantra I pointed out one such possible slight difference, albeit from a single dictionary (which is actually an advantage compared to looking up one word in one dictionary and the other word in a different dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Privation is an exclusion without having had anything;  whereas Deprivation implies having had the thing in the first place.

In deprivation something is taken away;  In privation it is inherent to the makeup of the individual.

Comment: Do you have a source to substantiate your understanding?

Answer (score 0):

I've have only seen this word today in an article. So from what I have read I understand deprivation to be short term and privation long term.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Your answer would benefit from linked references to support your claim.